# Join consecutive pairs of strings in a list if they meet a condition

Tags: python, string, list, concatenation

Given two lists:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","b","d","f","c","b","e"]
list2 = ["b","c"]
```

with the assumption `len(list2) == 2`,

I was wondering how to get an output like this:

```
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'bc', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

Essentially any instance of list2 within list1 (in that order), should concatenate in the original list1 and output (after checking all possibilities).

What I tried so far:

```
l = len(list1)

for i in range(0,l-1):
    if list1[i] == list2[0]:
        if list1[i+1] == list2[1]:
            a = i
            b = i+1
            list1[a:b+1] = [''.join(list1[a:b+1])]
            l = l - 1
            print(list1)
```

But keep getting an error:

```
if list1[i] == list2[0]: IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: One more test case:
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","b","d","f","c","b","c"]

Comment: Just an assumption: In your list1 count is 14 and when you manipulate the data for your output the array count is 12. Please check is this the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach using list slicing.

**Ex:**

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","b","d","f","c","b","e"]
list2 = ["b","c"]

l = len(list2)
result = []
skip = 0
for i, v in enumerate(list1):
    if skip:
        skip -= 1
        continue
    if list1[i:l+i] == list2:           #Check for sub-element
        result.append("".join(list2))
        skip = l-1                      #Skip flag
    else:
        result.append(v)
print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'bc', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

Comment: Really nice! I was wondering if you can try for any list2 length!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, should work for any length of `list2` :

```
split_pattern = ''.join(list2)
chunks = ''.join(list1).split(split_pattern)

result = list(chunks[0])
for c in chunks[1:] :
    result.append( split_pattern )
    result.extend( list(c) )
```

checking the `result` :

```
>>> result
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'bc', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question is why you are getting an error, this line

```
                list1[a:b+1] = [''.join(list1[a:b+1])]
```

modifies list1, and actually makes it shorter. So when you are looping on a range that is the length of list 1, making the list shorter means that the loop counter `i` will eventually be out of range, because the elements of the list you intended to find with the index are gone.

You also need to remember that lists are indexed from `0` to `n - 1`, where n is the length of the list, so this statement

```
if list1[i+1] == list2[1]:
```

looks like it really should be

```
if list[i] == list2[0]:
```

Also the outer loop is based on `range(0, l - 1)` means that it will loop through every index except the last one. So unless you really want to avoid looking at the last element of the list, which I don't think you do based on your requirements, you would use `range(l)`, which produces indexes from `0 to l - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","b","d","f","c","b","e"]
list2 = ["b","c"]
l = len(list1)
new_list = []
last_merge = False

for i in range(0,l):
    # match list1 index i element with list2 first element
    if list1[i] == list2[0]:
        # match list1 index i+1 element with list2 second element
        if i+1 <= l and list1[i+1] == list2[1]:
            # merge and append list1 index i and i+1 element
            new_list.append(list1[i]+list1[i+1])
            # mark merge as true
            last_merge = True
        else:
            # append list1 index i element
            new_list.append(list1[i])
    else:
        # check list index i element is merge with last element then mark last_merge as False and continue iterate list
        if last_merge is True:
            last_merge = False
            continue

        # append list1 index i element
        new_list.append(list1[i])

print(new_list)
```

O/P:

```
['a', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'bc', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Version with arbitrary list2 length:

```
def sublist_concatenate(list1, list2):
    N = len(list2)
    fullset = ''.join(list2)
    outlist = []
    i = 0  # counts the number of matches so far

    for el in list1:
        if el == list2[i]:  # hold matching elements so far
            i += 1
            if i == N:  # we have matched N times, so we have the whole set
                outlist.append(fullset)
                i = 0
        else:  # not a match for the next position
            outlist += list2[0:i] # add all previously-passed elements
            # check whether it is a match for the first position though
            if el == list2[0]:
                i = 1
            else:
                outlist.append(el)
                i = 0

    return outlist


l1 = ["a", "b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",
      "b", "c", "b", "d", "f", "c", "b", "e"]
l2 = ["b", "c"]

print sublist_concatenate(l1, l2)
# ['a', 'b', 'bc', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'bc', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

EDIT: code fixed per comments, adding the `if el == list2[0]` branch.

Comment: failing for input `l1 = ["a", "b","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "b", "c", "b", "d", "f", "c", "b", "e"]`

Comment: Good catch (reason is that `"b", "b"` makes the logic fail). Will try to fix it.

Comment: you need to reset i=0 when next element doesn't match

Answer (score 0):

```
def new_f(l1,l2):
    for i,j in zip(l2,l1):
        if i!=j:
            return False
    return True


def func(l1,l2):

    res=[]    
    index = 0    
    l2_string = ''.join(l2)

    while index<len(l1):        
        if l1[index]==l2[0] and new_f(l1[index:index+len(l2)], l2):          # if first element found then checck compare with list2
            # compare with list2 if elemnt match with first elment of list2
            res.append(l2_string)
            index+=len(l2)
        else:
            res.append(l1[index])               
        index+=1
    return res

list1 = ["a", "b","b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "b", "c", "b", "d", "f", "c", "b", "e"]
list2 = ["b", "c"]

result= func(list1,list2)
print(result)
```

output

```
    ['a', 'b', 'bc', 'e', 'f', 'bc', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'b', 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to suggest this method which returns a generator:

```
def join_if_ref(main_list, ref_list):
  n, s = len(ref_list), "".join(ref_list)
  i, size = 0, len(main_list)
  while i < size-n+1:
    j = "".join(main_list[i:i+n])
    if j == s:
      yield j
      i += n - 1
    else:
      yield main_list[i]
    if i < size: i += 1
  for k in range(size-i):
    yield(main_list[k+i])
```

In this case:

```
list1 = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","b","c","b","d","f","c","b","c","d","k","s"]
list2 = ["b","c","d"]
```

It returns:

```
res = join_if_ref(list1, list2)
print(list(res))
#=> ['a', 'bcd', 'e', 'f', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'f', 'c', 'bcd', 'k', 's']
```